# Let $B = \{a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{5}: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$. Does B possess the least upper bound property?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $B = \{a + b\sqrt{2} + c\sqrt{3} + d\sqrt{5}: a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Q}\}$

Does $B$ possess the least upper bound property?

I know that $B$ will have the least upper bound property if every non-empty subset of B which is bounded from above has a supremum in $B$. However, I am a bit lost on how to go about showing this.

Comment: Can you show $\mathbf Q$ does *not* have the least upper bound property without using the real numbers $\sqrt{2}$, $\sqrt{3}$, or $\sqrt{5}$ as upper bounds on a subset of the rational numbers?

Comment: I note that generally proof used is to show that the subset $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: x^2 \leq 2\}$ has an upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$ but does not have a supremum in $\mathbb{Q}$ since $\sqrt{2}$ is irrational. The same principle would work for other irrational numbers such as $\sqrt{7}$.

Comment: The answer is no, because $B$ is countable but is dense in $\Bbb{R}$, so that for any $x \in \Bbb{R}$, $x = \sup\{y : B \mid y < x\}$.

Comment: Consider $\{ x \in B \mid x \lt \pi \}$.

Comment: @RobertShore yeah that looks like a nice option!